# Saving data with XML - file being used by another process

Tags: xml, vb.net

I am new to Visual Basic, and am creating a basic task manager program.  I wanted to save my data in a xml file.

When it first loads it checks if the xml file exists and if not creates it

```
Private Sub frmTaskManager_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    'Checks if tasks exists
    If IO.File.Exists("tasks.xml") Then
        GetSavedTasks()
    Else
        'Creates xml document
        CreateXMLDocument()
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub CreateXMLDocument()
        'If tasks don't exists then creates a new xml file
        Dim settings As New XmlWriterSettings()
        settings.Indent = True

        ' Initialize the XmlWriter.
        Dim XmlWrt As XmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create("Tasks.xml", settings)
        With XmlWrt
            ' Write the Xml declaration.
            .WriteStartDocument()

            ' Write a comment.
            .WriteComment("XML Database.")

            ' Write the root element.
            .WriteStartElement("Tasks")

            ' Close the XmlTextWriter.
            .WriteEndDocument()
            .Close()
        End With
    End Sub
```

The first time it creates it I can add to it using my save method after they enter a description of the task.  Here is how I save.

```
Public Sub Save()
    Dim xmlDoc As XmlDocument = New XmlDocument()
    xmlDoc.Load("Tasks.xml")

    With xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("Tasks").CreateNavigator.AppendChild
        .WriteStartElement("task")
        .WriteElementString("description", Description)
        .WriteEndElement()
        .Flush()
        .Close()
        .Dispose()
    End With
    xmlDoc.Save("Tasks.xml")
End Sub
```

Everything works fine the first time, when the xml document does NOT exist.  The second time I start my project I get an error when I try to add to the xml file saying 
"An unhandled exception of type 'System.IO.IOException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: The process cannot access the file 'C:\Users\Josh\SkyDrive\Projects\Visual Basic\Task Manager\Task Manager\bin\Debug\Tasks.xml' because it is being used by another process."

Any ideas what could be causing this?  Also is XML a bad choice to store data in for a VB project?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not disposing the `XmlWriter` (it is not enough just with closing it) and that's why the second time an error is triggered (the object is still "alive"). `Using` takes care of everything (disposing and closing):

```
 Using XmlWrt As XmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create("Tasks.xml", settings)
     With XmlWrt
         ' Write the Xml declaration.
         .WriteStartDocument()

         ' Write a comment.
         .WriteComment("XML Database.")

         ' Write the root element.
         .WriteStartElement("Tasks")

         ' Close the XmlTextWriter.
         .WriteEndDocument()
     End With
 End Using
```